# Xamarin iOS Error simctl returned exit code 4

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Three days ago, my app ran well and deployed smoothly to Emulator on my mac until today when I tried to run again, my apps cannot run with the error

Error on Visual Studio

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.appname' on the device 'iOS 16.4 (xxxxx) - iPhone 14 Pro': simctl returned exit code 4
```

I have tried to

1. Clear emulator data by Device -> Erase all content and Settings
2. Check xCode  -> Preferences -> Location -> Command Line Tools  set to xCode 14.3.1 (14E300c)
3. Check on the ios project properties -> iOS build -> Supported Architecture to i386 + x86_x64

When I try to run manually the `simctl` here is the result

```
xcrun simctl install xxxx-D7E4-4571-A0B9  xxxx/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/app.iOS/a17f6534d68e8b9asdasdsadasdcc5319a6aed7589eecdf4b78edea37d73c0de0d639f43d/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/MyApp.app
```

And the result is

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=4):
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
This app needs to be updated by the developer to work on this version of iOS.
Failed to find matching arch for input file: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxx-D7E4-4571-xxx-xxx/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iMe6mP/extracted/MaxGoiOS.app/app
Underlying error (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=4):
    “MyApp” Needs To Be Updated
    This app needs to be updated by the developer to work on this version of iOS.
```

I use `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current - Version 17.6.4` and
`Mac Book Pro 2018 Ventura 13.5 Intel Core`

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: According to the error log, consider changing the supported architecture to `Arm64` to see if it works fine.

Comment: It's on emulators not on the real devices

Comment: Have you tried to change it?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT There is no Arm64 option when targeting iPhoneSimulator